# will this google cloud function cause an infinite loop on firestore trigger?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that listens to updates to a path in firestore

```
export const onUserWrite = functions.firestore.document('/path/path').onWrite(async (change) => {
  if (!change.after.exists) {
    return;
  }
  await change.after.ref.update({somedata:'data'});

  return true;
});
```

I think this will cause an infinite loop because, this code `await change.after.ref.update({somedata:'data'});` should trigger the function again, thus causing an infinite loop.

if so why wouldn't the documentation mention this?

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that this specific function will result in an infinite loop. Since it is listening for [any writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_for_all_changes_to_a_document) in Firestore, it will execute itself again when the `await` statement updates the current document using the `ref` (DocumentReference) [property](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html) of the change parameter (which is a DocumentSnapshot).

The Firebase Functions repository does include similar [sample functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/text-moderation/functions/index.js#L23), and a way to deal with potential infinite loops is to implement checks before updating Firestore. This avoids infinite recursive calls to the same function. For the sample function I linked, when a new change is detected, the document will be updated and this specific function avoids infinite recursive calls by checking first for a document property to be set to true.

```
exports.moderator = 
functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onWrite((change) => {
  const message = change.after.val();
    //If document is sanitized, skip the function
  if (message && !message.sanitized) {
    //...
    return change.after.ref.update({
      text: moderatedMessage,
      sanitized: true,
      moderated: message.text !== moderatedMessage,
    });
    //Sanitized the document, when this function runs again due to this update, it will be skipped
  }
  return null;
});
```

You can also check this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865161/) for different approaches to take.

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can click on the checkmark icon to mark it as accepted. This can help future users who are having the same issue.